# getjson jquery doesn't work in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, cordova

I'm trying to retrieve json data from local server in my phonegap android app.
I've put a submit input to get data.I am using the method $.ajax in jquery to do that. 
My problem is that when i click the submit, nothing is displayed but the page is refreshed.
I don't see how to fix this.

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

(ps: the json returned is correct and i've changed the access in config.xml)

Here is the full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Application test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#testform').submit(function(){
       $('#content').html("<b>Chargement...</b>");

        $.ajax({
         url:  "http://localhost/projects/api/getAllCategorie.php"
         }).done(function(data){

            $("#content").html('<p> ID: ' + data.categories[0].id + '</p>');
            log('erreur');
        }).fail(function(){
             alert("Erreur!!");
             $("#content").html('erreur');
             log('erreur');
        });     
         return false;
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src= "css/images/logo-annuaire-mayotte.png">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter placeholder="Rechercher..." data-inset="true">
     <li><a href="#">Restaurants</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Bâtiments</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Numéros utiles</a></li>
  </ul>
<form id='testform'>
   <div><input type="submit" id="driver" value="Synchronisation" /></div>
</form>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this "local" server on android device/emulator? if no, why are you using localhost? localhost on android device/emulator means device/emulator itself not your PC

Comment: i'm using localhost because later i will put the data on distant server. What should i do ?

Comment: you should learn how to use google.com ... localhost is localhost ... as i wrote localhost on emulator means emulator itself not a host of emulator(unless you do some changes in hosts file)

Comment: I now put 12.0.2.2 instead but it still doesn't work. (I'am maybe asking some dumbs questions, sorry i'm new in this).

Comment: yes sorry it's 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to connect to your localhost php file use port number(working for me) or IP address of your actual system like this

   ```
   http:// localhost:8080/projects/api/getAllCategorie.php,(for emulator) 
   http:// 10.0.2.2/projects/api/getAllCategorie.php
   ```
2. Close your document ready function

   ```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#driver').click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault(); // To prevent default action of the form
          $('#content').html("<b>Chargement...</b>");
           $.ajax({

            url:  "http://localhost:8080/projects/api/getAllCategorie.php",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                   alert("Request is going to send now");// place your loader 
            },
            success:function(data){
               $("#content").html('<p> ID: ' + data.categories[0].id + '</p>');
               log('erreur');
            },             
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
             alert(xhr.responseText);
                $("#content").html('erreur');
                log('erreur');
            }
            });     
            return false;
       });
       });
   ```

**HTMl** : Replace your form tag with this input tag

```
     <div><input type="button" id="driver" value="Synchronisation" /></div>
```